# DocuSign API - Recipient email address changed automatically by DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

We have a very straight-forward DocuSign integration where the users can add signers and send document for signing from our document management tool and the signer level updates are automatically fetched by tool and available to requester within our tool itself.

We recently ran into a rather unexpected situation with our DocuSign integration, wherein DocuSign updated/changed/resolved one of the signer's email address to a different email address. Thus, whenever we (tool) tried to fetch the updates corresponding to that signer, DocuSign kept returning null pointer exception (as the signer with that email no longer existed for the DocuSign).

On after retrieving the audit details for this envelope, we were able to understand the above issue. This was logged in DocuSign envelope history as "Recipient email resolved". On DocuSign Admin account, this entry is shown as below:

[DocuSign Envelope History Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY3Vw.jpg)

I have tried to dig into DocuSign documentation (product & API both) to know more about "Recipient email resolved" action but to no avail.

My queries are -

- Has anyone run into similar situation in past?
- What is the root cause/reason because of which DocuSign automatically resolves (changes) the email address of the recipient?
- Is there a way to suppress this behavior? If not, is there a way to retrieve the status update against original email address instead of having to manually update the email in our tool?

Additional Information:

- Our tool is built such that it allows the customers to configure their own DocuSign account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email address rarely changes. This only happens on occasions where the signer has specifically provided DocuSign with their preferred email address and alternates. There's no option for you to suppress this behavior. 
You can check the envelope to get the signer information later to see the change if you wish.
Hope this helps